# VBA Code to select a range of dates for Reservation spreadsheet

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to adapt what I've found online to meet my needs.  I'm trying to set up a Reservation system.  As I currently have it set up I enter the following information on sheet1 (reservation).  I'm using a different macro to store all of that info on sheet2 (data).
    Name:
    Site #
    Start Date: 1/3/2015
    End Date:   1/7/2015
    Pets:   No
    Club:
    Phone #:
    Status:

What I would like to be able to do is to populate a "calendar" of what site is being used on what date. I would like the customer's name to show up in the correct site row on their "start date".  I would like their range of dates with me to  be highlighted in the correct color code of their "status".

The code that I'm trying to modify only selected the start date and it puts their "status" in that box.  I've included the code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
thanks,
Henry

Sub Bookings()

```
Dim Rm As Range, Dt As Range, Myrng As Range, Sites As Range
Dim endCol As Range, StCol As Range, StRow As Range, endRow As Range
Dim Codei As Range, Col As Range
Dim Dws As Worksheet, Cws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, dCell As Range

Set Cws = Reservation
Set Dws = Data
Set StCol = Cws.Range("AL3")
Set endCol = Cws.Range("AN3")
Set StRow = Cws.Range("AP3")
Set endRow = Cws.Range("AR3")

LastRow = Dws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Myrng = Dws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)   'data sheet columns
Cws.Range("C15:AD83").ClearContents
Cws.Range("C15:AD83").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    For x = StRow To endRow
    Set Sites = Cws.Cells(x, 2)
            For Each d Cell In Cws.Range(Cells(x, StCol), Cells(x, endCol))
        If Not dCell Is Nothing Then
            Set Dt = Cells(11, dCell.Column)
                            Set aCell = Myrng.Find(What:=Sites, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Set bCell = aCell
                                    Do
                    Set aCell = Myrng.FindNext(After:=aCell)
                    If aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Dt.Value Then
                        Set Codei = aCell.Cells(1, 4)
                        Set Col = aCell.Cells(1, 3)
                        dCell.Value = Codei
                        Select Case Col
                            Case Cws.Range("AJ3").Value
                                dCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                            Case Cws.Range("AJ4").Value
                                dCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                            Case Cws.Range("AJ5").Value
                                dCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                            Case Cws.Range("AJ6").Value
                                dCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                        End Select
                    End If
                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop

            End If
        End If
    Next dCell

Next

On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub